# How do I merge 2 (or more) "visio websites" (*.htm) with subpages?

Tags: html, merge, visio, organization, presentation

I created various flowcharts of processes with the latest visio of a small, complex company (not done yet, but there will be approximately 8 visio files, each with 3-6 sheets).

I am currently looking for a way to present the final result, my idea is to save those files as a website (VML). The problem however is, that I want one single file: therefore my question, how can I merge those files?

I tried to use my very limited html knowledge, the site didn't open anymore. I tried to use "Microsoft Expression Web 4" and just copied 2 test files in there, but it was not usable. My goal is to have on the left side contents, which are linked to the actual visio drawings (think: visio file1 - sheets1.1-1.5; visio file2 - sheets2.1-2.3,...)

Thanks a lot for any help (or other ideas), I am going crazy over this!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I copied the code from both files into one and saved it as newfile.htm, I also edited the code within expression web, as it seemed the easiest solution for someone with little knowledge like me.

Answer (score 0):

How much easier would it be to merge the drawings in Visio itself, before exporting to HTML. Just open the files side-by-side and drag the pages from one document to the other. You may need to press the control key to avoid moving the shapes instead of copying them.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I guess it is much easier to change the html code to create 'chapters', rather than merging single files... Do you also have a suggestion for connecting/storing dicuments that are related to processes?

Comment: What do you mean by "connecting/storing documents"? and why specially "processes?

Comment: I am creating BPMN flow charts and on a page there are multiple tasks, gateways etc, some of them use documents which i want to connect accordingly (eg a bill is being processed, i want to show an example of the bill as PDF or image)